# Flume 1.6.0 Agent start failed

Tags: hadoop, jar, flume, flume-ng

I have an issue while starting an apache flume agent with the flume-ng file within the bin folder.
I have no clue how to fix this. I just wanted to run a flume example.
I´m using CentOS (Linux distribution), only command line.

Below you can see my config-file.

```
agent1.sources = source1
agent1.sinks = sink1
agent1.channels = channel1

agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1

agent1.sources.source1.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.source1.spoolDir = /tmp/spooldir

agent1.sinks.sink1.type = logger

agent1.channels.channel1.type = file
```

I try to run the agent with the following command:

```
bin/flume-ng agent -f conf/spooling.conf -c $FLUME_HOME/bin -n agent1
```

Also FLUME_HOME is set: ~/opt/flume

when I´m trying to run this I will get die below output:

```
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/opt/hadoop/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Fehler: Hauptklasse org.apache.flume.tools.GetJavaProperty konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Info: Excluding /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar from classpath
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /opt/jdk/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/root/opt/flume/bin:/root/opt/flume/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1-tests.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/jdiff:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/sources:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/templates:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1-tests.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/jdiff:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/sources:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/templates:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/sources:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/test:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1-tests.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib-examples:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application -f conf/spooling.conf -n agent1
Fehler: Hauptklasse org.apache.flume.node.Application konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
```

I think, the problem is the failure of two .jar-file imports, but have no idea how to handle this.
Could somebody help me?

Thanks in advance,

Doe

Comment: Some of the logs are in german (or something like that) and I cannot totally figure out what is really happening :) I'll recommend you to edit the question by translating those lines.

Answer (score 0):

This command:

```
bin/flume-ng agent -f conf/spooling.conf -c $FLUME_HOME/bin -n agent1
```

is wrong. The '-c' option is about the configuration folder. With '-f' you specify the specific configuration for the agent, and with '-c' you specify the entire configuration folder where other relevant configuration files such as log4j, flume-env.sh etc are located. Try:

```
bin/flume-ng agent -f conf/spooling.conf -c conf -n agent1
```